# xcode 8 & swift 3 - PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization crashing

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3, ios10

I have upgraded my project to swift 3 and working with Xcode 8
Now when I want to access the photos I get a crash, with no information in the console.

I have added "Privacy - Photo Library Usage Description" to my info.plist.
Please see images below for more information.
Thanks
Reza

[image]
[image]

[image: info.plist entries]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There appeared to be multiple .plists in my project and by mistake I had edited the wrong .plist

Answer (score 2):

Proper way to do is

```
let status = PHPhotoLibrary.authorizationStatus()
    switch status {
    case .authorized: 

    case .denied, .restricted :

    //handle denied status
    case .notDetermined:
        // ask for permissions
        PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization() { (status) -> Void in
            switch status {
            case .authorized:

            // as above
            case .denied, .restricted: 

            // as above
            case .notDetermined: break
                // won't happen but still
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: That is exactly how I am trying to do it. As soon as I call PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization() I get this odd crash